# Prevent update of column except by trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, permissions

Is it possible to configure a Postgres database such that a specific column may only be updated by a trigger, while still allowing the trigger itself to be executed in response to an update by a role without permission to update that column? If so, how?

For example, given tables and a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TABLE a(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  flag boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
  data text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE b(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  updated_on DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
  a_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (a_id) references a(id)
);

CREATE FUNCTION update_aflag() RETURNS trigger AS $update_aflag$
  BEGIN
    UPDATE a
    SET flag = FALSE
    WHERE id = NEW.a_id;
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$update_aflag$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_aflag_trigger
  AFTER INSERT ON b
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_aflag()
;
```

I'd like to define a role which does *not* have permission to update `a.flag` directly using an `UPDATE` statement, but which *may* update `flag` indirectly via the trigger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using a `SECURITY DEFINER` trigger function. The trigger function runs as a role that has the right to modify the `flag` column, but you don't `GRANT` that right to normal users. You should create the trigger function as the role that you'll grant the required rights to.

This requires that the application not run as the user that owns the tables, and of course not as a superuser.

You can `GRANT` column update rights to other columns to the user, just leave out the `flag` column. Note that `GRANT`ing `UPDATE` on all columns then `REVOKE`ing it on `flag` will *not* work, it's not the same thing.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed answer Craig. Going to read through the documentation now and try to come up with an appropriate `SECURITY DEFINER` trigger function :)